# Unable to send emails from my office email account configured in outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am unable to send emails from my Outlook 2007. I have configuredmy office email account in outlook few months back and it was working fine untill a couple of days back. Not sure what happened, now I am not able to send any email only though outlook. But, I am able to recieve all the emails.

I have tested the setting once and I go this message "Send test e-mail message: The server responded: 421 Cannot connect to SMT". Can anyone please help me in resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could the message have referenced SMTP rather than SMT?  I'm wondering if somehow the port setting for your outgoing mail got changed.  Port 465 is commonly used for SMTP.  Check that setting.  If you aren't sure what port number it should be, identify the email service provider in the account.

Comment: I believe 465 is for secured connection and 25 is for non secured connection, please correct me if I am wrong. All this while I have been using 25 as a non secured connection but I even tried with 465 which gave me a timeout error.

Comment: Check your provider's 'how to send email' page for the SMTP details - mine recently changed the SMTP address without telling anyone.

Comment: If the issue is the port, I'm not aware that 421 is ever used, so that would explain the problem.  Fixing it requires finding out what it is supposed to be.